# Online language exercises

Tags: learning, online-resource

I'm looking for web sites that might have exercises for beginners and intermediate users.

So far I found [Duolingo](http://www.duolingo.com) and [DeutschAkademie](http://www.deutschakademie.de/online-deutschkurs/english), and although they are excellent sites, after a while they get kind of repetitive.

I've been attending a German course for the past 18 months, but we have lectures only once a week (for 4 hours), and I would like to improve my learning process by doing exercises online in my free time.

Do you have any recommendations on such sites?

Comment: I have no recommendations for resources but I do recommend that you get used to repetition if you intend to learn any language (or anything for that matter).  Repetition is the proven key to success.

Comment: Oh, I agree with that, but the sites I mentioned have a relatively small knowledge base (to be fair, it is increased from time to time), but I wanted to further improve my vocabulary, so I was looking for additional sources (obviously reading a dictionary is not always useful, nor nearly as fun as these sites)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On online learning, the [Memrise](https://www.memrise.com/) helps me a lot, when I want to learn the new words. They claim they are using a special method to trigger the learning process.

In addition to Memrise, the [Goethe institute](https://www.goethe.de/prj/dfd/de/home.cfm) provides a community to learn German together. There are hunderds of execises for listening, writing and reading.

If you stick to these websites, you will advance your German shortly.

Comment: Memrise is really good

Comment: @NDraskovic I am happy that you found it useful. There, I have learnt more than 7000 words :)

Comment: The only problem I'm having with it so far is that it seems to be teaching things by heart, without actually explaining why something is formed as it is. For instance, it doesn't explain the difference between "aß" and "gegessen" (I know the difference, I'm just making a point), but in combination with Duolingo, this might be a powerful tool

Comment: @NDraskovic Yes, I understand but the site is for learning new words, not the grammar. I mean it is the technological version of the word cards, which people used in the past. Learning a new language has lots of dimensions and all of the dimensions should be satisfied to master it. Because of this reason, as you said, you should combine different sources for a full learning.

Comment: Agreed. Like I said, I'm looking for additional resources to help me out, I still consider that course to be my primary learning tool. Thanks again for the reference

Answer (score 1):

A huge resource is Deutsche Welle (DW), Germany's Public Broadcasting network, which provides an enormous amount of free resources to learn the German language.  It provides text, videos and exercises at all speaking levels, A1 through C2.

http://www.dw.com/de/deutsch-lernen/s-2055

Answer (score 1):

I really like this page:

http://www.deutschalsfremdsprache.ch/index.php?actualid=5057&which_set=101

as there is a lot of useful materials, that also have interesting form. I used to give it to my students. Well, at least some of them.